# How to get platform of the current device?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, watchos, uidevice

Is there a way to get the current platform of the device? I'm hoping for a better way than to do something like this:

let platform: String

```
#if os(iOS)
platform = "iOS"
#elseif os(watchOS)
platform = "watchOS"
#elseif os(tvOS)
platform = "tvOS"
#elseif os(macOS)
platform = "macOS"
#else
platform = "unknown"
#endif
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How about `UIDevice.current.systemName`?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't present in macOS

Comment: Do you want a compile time or run time check?  The code you have is a compile time check.  For a runtime check you need to consider things like Mac catalyst and iOS apps running under macOS on Apple Silicon (You can use a `ProcessInfo` property for these)

Comment: At runtime is what I was looking for